# Is it unethical to poorly translate an exam from Dutch to English and then present it to the English speaking students?

Tags: ethics, exams, language, translations, netherlands

There are two tracks for my field of study. One is taught in Dutch and the other in English. This is in the Netherlands.  A while ago we had to take a multiple choice exam in English, which looked a bit odd. The sentence construction of the questions makes little sense at first glance, and it took a while to even grasp the content. Furthermore, it seemed quite obvious that the exam was only roughly translated (possibly by a machine) as the exam just sounded as if someone used a thesaurus to make it. In addition some of the answer options were still in Dutch, which made it *extremely* difficult to understand the content. Moreover, some questions had literally the same answer option twice.

So in summary, the students in the English track took the botched translation version, while the students in the Dutch track took the Dutch version.

Is it unethical to give English speaking students a poorly translated version of the same exam that the Dutch students receive?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions. The title would apply to a competently translated exam. The body of the question discusses a badly translated exam.

Comment: No, this is not OK. Report to the board of examiners relevant for your degree immediately.

Comment: Ahh, Aüslander tax (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78058/) - deal with it an move on.

Comment: It would only be unethical if they did it on purpose - more likely, it's just sloppiness.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor  Of course, it's still worth trying to get it rectified.

Comment: @NateEldredge is it ethical for an academic program to treat its students sloppily?  I don't think so.

Comment: @phoog It's _wrong_ for an academic program to treat its students sloppily, but it is probably _counterproductive_ to call it unethical; that term immediately makes people think you are accusing them of having done something much more serious (e.g. plagiarism), _on purpose_.  Treating this as sloppiness -- even if there may have been some malice in there somewhere -- is much more likely to achieve a good outcome.

Comment: "A while ago we had to take a multiple choice exam, which looked a bit odd. The sentence construction of the questions makes little sense at first glance, and it took a while to even grasp the content." - in my experience, this is more a feature inherent to the method of extensive multiple choice testing than anything else.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying the students in the English track took the botched translation version, while the students in the Dutch track took the Dutch version?  //  It's generally a good idea to read University policy very, very carefully, and if possible us that as the basis for a complaint.

Comment: @aparente001 that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: The specific course of action depends somewhat on whether this was an isolated occurrence.  Has anyone spoken with a dean or the department head?  It would be an easy matter for the department to take a look at the exam.  (Do check university policy -- this can give you ammunition.)

Comment: It helps if you quantify the impact of the bad translation: *"The exam was X hours long and we spent on average Y% of that attempting to understand the question meaning"* Was it like 1% or 25%? Did anyone actually write a wrong answer because of the translation? etc.

Comment: @smci: Indeed. That is kind of what I tried to point out in [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/79447/14017). "Bad" exam questions can sometimes be "rescued" in the grading phase, and only then one can determine whether more answers ended up "wrong" because of the issues with the exam.

Comment: ...and were there any particularly bad telltale questions which the English-speakers got wrong much more?

Comment: Sounds to me like someone clueless thought they were doing you a favor and royally screwed it up.

Comment: @WetlabWalter you cannot just randomly put umlauts into a word. That's just plain wrong.

Comment: Deäl wïth ït B-) [...but yes it should be Ausländer not Aüslander]

Answer (score 34):

There are two different questions in here that are mixed up: one about whether the Dutch and English exams should be identical and one about exam quality.

Regarding the first question: I fail to see why this should be unethical. On the contrary: It seems very *good* that the standards on what you are supposed to know are the same. After all, you get the same degree.

Regarding the second question: Also here, the answer is obvious: Of course, exams need to be of good quality. If that is not the case, sure, this is a problem to be addressed. But that has nothing to do with the question of whether they are a translation or not.

Comment: Unequal treatment of the students in the class is a problem beyond simply  "quality".

Answer (score 23):

I wanted to add an answer that concentrates more specifically on the issues of *fairness* and *ethics*.

Along with some (but not all) of the commenters, I don't think it is a good idea to characterize a poorly written exam as an *ethical problem* (without further information; it is a strange feature of ethical problems that almost anything *could become an ethical problem* under certain circumstances).  A poorly written exam is problematic *because it is poorly written*.  One does not need to launch an investigation of *why* the exam was poorly written in order to complain about it or seek redress for it.

I find (and have written here elsewhere) that students have a very strong sense of "fairness" and often want things to be completely fair.  We could be completely fair by giving all students everywhere the same grades; otherwise I believe it is provably impossible to be completely fair in all situations.  Different students are taught by instructors of different levels of abilities or enthusiasms at universities with differing resources in countries with differing resources...and so forth.  As a student, there is always going to be some other student who is in a more favorable situation than you.  It is not reasonable to ask for otherwise.  What is reasonable is to (i) ask to be treated *well* rather than *badly* and (ii) be willing to change from one academic situation to another if you see a better opportunity.

In this particular case:

> Is this fair to the students in the English track? Is it even ethical?

Neither one is the right question.  Imagine there was no Dutch track, or imagine the Dutch track was experiencing the mirror image situation: getting exams that are poorly translated from English.  It would be fair, and arguably ethical, to give poorly translated exams to *everyone*.  But it would be *bad* for all parties.  As a student you deserve to have exams which are not so poorly written that fluent speakers of the language have trouble understanding the wording of the questions.  And you should ask for that.  In my view it does not strengthen your case to ask for exams which are "as good as the Dutch track": rather they should be good, full stop.  If they aren't, and if faculty there are not interested in conducting their business well rather than badly, consider going elsewhere.

Comment: I would guess that the ethics part of the question comes from the inequality in exam clarity for the two groups of students (dutch-speaking and non). There is perhaps identical input to both groups, but the exam difficulty varies (due to quality issues in one case). I remember a similar problem also at a Dutch university - Dutch-speaking students were given extra materials because some materials existed only in Dutch. This ended up being an advantage for the exam. In my example, the exam was identical but the input was not. Regardless of the quality of materials, it was still unethical.

Comment: @Ana: I understand what you are saying.  But it seems to me first of all that the exam was poorly written in a way which cannot be intentional.  (If you are in an English track, having portions of exams being written in a language other than English must be a mistake, right?)  Second: I would like to think that a university which has parallel tracks for different languages would want to treat those two tracks in a uniform way.  But is it obviously unethical if they don't?...

Comment: ...  It's hard to believe that a Dutch university could be obligated by some basic principle to give English courses and exams at all: my understanding is that this is something that universities in the Netherlands choose to do.  If they are choosing to do it, they get to choose how to implement it.  If they implement it badly enough, they will lose students that they don't want to lose.  Looking at it ethically doesn't seem to get to the heart of the issue.

Comment: By the way: as a postdoc I taught at McGill University in Montreal.  McGill is an English language university within the mostly Francophone Canadian province of Quebec.  Natively Francophone students had some enumerated rights -- e.g. they could ask for an assignment or exam be translated into French.  All the textbooks we used were in English, and all the study materials were in English.  Is that unethical?  I would say: you can debate that if you like, but the practical answer is that that's how McGill University works.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think this too clever by half.  Universities can and do get away with a lot of bad behavior, but that doesn't somehow make it justified.  Agreeing to teach a course in a particular language, and not properly translating the materials into that language is malpractice.   It's one thing to set a policy which may ultimately not assist students as much as they need (as in your McGill example), and another to set out a policy (we will teach this course in English) and carry it out incompetently.

Comment: @Ben: I agree with you -- it depends entirely on what the policy is.  But based on what has been said, it is very hard to believe that the university has been competent in enacting its policy.  It should do better.  So this is an incompetence issue, not really an ethical one.  In the event that the OP's program wants to insist that there is no problem with giving badly-machine-translated exams, it still seems fruitless for the OP to take them to task for ethical violations.  Even if he succeeds, the root problem of their gross incompetence would still be there.

Comment: I agree with this answer and the comments below. We frequently receive questions which refer to possible ethical problems when there is no ethical problem at all. There are good and bad courses as there are good and bad products, and usually their goodness or badness has nothing to do with ethics: some people is simply better than others at doing their stuff. In the OP's case, the professor and the university might have overestimated the professor's English skills. Or not, but they had no other alternative. The important thing is to give feedback and to ask for an improvement of the "product".

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: well did Francophone students tend to achieve lower than English-speaking, and by how much?

Comment: @BenWebster: the status of French vs English in Canadian education is a long story, and depends on what province you're in. How unfeasible and expensive would it be to mandate bilingual English-French staff and texts for everything, and how much extra would it all cost? And they didn't "agree to teach a course in a particular language", it's [Quebec Bill 101/Charter of the French Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charter_of_the_French_Language) which mandates it.

Comment: An exam written in _bad_ english would actually be unfair towards anyone whose English isn't perfect (for example non-native English speakers with not very much experience). To these people, bad English is much much more difficult than to native English speakers. On the other hand, badly translated Dutch would probably put native Dutch speakers at an unfair advantage, who might be the only ones figuring out what it means.

Comment: @smci You seem to have completely misread my comment.  I wasn't suggesting McGill needs to be bilingual; I was pointing out that they're situation isn't the same, precisely because they didn't claim to do instruction in French.  I was talking about the OP's situation.

Comment: @smci Students at McGill have chosen to study at an Anglophone university. Those who want a Francophone one go to Universite de Montreal instead.

Comment: @BenWebster: I didn't miss your point at all, I was reacting to the over-the-top claim *"Agreeing to teach a course in a particular language, and not properly translating the materials into that language is malpractice"*, wrt Bill 101, which mandates accommodations for French-language speakers, there's no question of "agreeing". To Jessica, Bill 101 applies to all of Quebec province, regardless. To all of you, I don't think it's helpful to mix that up with the OP's example. I'd be interested in a new question: "How does English- and French-language university instruction work in Quebec?"

Comment: @PeteL.Clark (regarding your second comment): Dutch universities are indeed not obligated to provide English language courses. If they do provide an English language program (alongside or instead of a Dutch one) it has to meet the same standards as any other program. If they implement it badly enough, not only do students stop coming, they will also lose any government financing for the program and their right to award a degree for the program (of course a single bad exam is unlikely to lead to that). So while they choose to, they cannot google translate their program and be done with it.

Comment: @Smci I know it's dumb to argue about this, but I just can't help myself: if you understood, then you knew that the fragment you just quoted wasn't about Quebec, and thus has nothing to do with Bill 101, and so your comment makes no sense.  I'll additionally say that it's malpractice to do a bad job translating exams when you are legally obliged to, but that's a different question entirely.  All I meant to say is, whatever policy you have, you should carry it out well.

Comment: @BenWebster: I did understand, and I said a) your sweeping claim on malpractice was over-the-top. I agree *"whatever policy... they should carry it out well"*, but that's aspiration, not reality, and if that's our yardstick, there's a ton of malpractice out there b) this question's joint Dutch-English language arrangement is so different to McGill and Quebec's mandatory policies, that it's confusing to mix or compare them. I guess we should stop at this.

Answer (score 4):

The key point is whether the poor quality of the exams affected the marks. If translation was poor but students could understand all questions - even with help of professors or assistants present at the exam - bad translation is just an small problem of lack of professionalism that should be fixed before next exam. However, if bad translation prevented students to produce good questions, then it's worse and there are grounds to ask for the exam be repeated.

And I wouldn't focus the issue in ethics. Of course, ethics command to offer students a good service without mistakes like this one, but I see this mistake more as a practical problem than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this fair to the students in the English track? Is it even ethical?

It is too early to answer this question. For an exam, a final judgment can only be spoken after the grades have been determined.

Certainly, the way you describe the translation, it seems to have been badly done. This should be avoided in exams - and yet, sometimes it isn't. However, when bad quality creeps into some aspect of an exam, there is always still the option of adjusting the grading. For instance, completely incrompehensible questions might be ignored while grading, ambiguous questions could be graded as correctly answered for either interpretation, etc.

Now, making exam questions truly unambiguous can be hard, and making two exams in two languages express exactly the same information is really hard. Whenever this is attempted, there is a high probability the two language versions will differ at least in some nuances. What is more, this is aggravated by the fact that each question is often designed by very few people (or even just one person), and they are usually not native in all languages the question needs to be written in. Hence, it is almost unavoidable that different language versions of an exam are somewhat "unfairly" different.

Now, if that difference is enough to have a noticeable effect (approximately as in, students complain that had they used the other version, they could have solved a question that they failed to solve), the way to go is to treat the language versions as different exams and slightly decouple their grading schemes. (This only works to a limited extent, when only a few questions are really problematic, before something may have to be done about the entire exam.)